# How to solve $y'+2 \sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{y}{2} +2x \cos^2 \frac{y}{2} = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following ODE:

$$y'+2 \sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{y}{2} +2x \cos^2 \frac{y}{2} = 0 $$

I'm stuck. I'm trying to get it to a linear form $y'+a(x)y=b(x)$ so that I can solve it. I've managed to get it to $$y' + \sin y - \sin^2 \frac{y}{2} +2x=0$$
using $\sin y = 2 \sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{y}{2}$ and $\cos^2 \frac{y}{2}  = 1-\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} $. But this still is not helping.

Thanks.

Comment: The $\sin y$ makes it nonlinear. Have you Separation of variables?

Comment: This is a nonlinear ODE. I *strongly doubt* it has any "nice" solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y'+2\sin(y/2) \cos(y/2)+2x\cos^2(y/2)=0 \implies \sec^2(y/2) y'+ 2\tan(y/2)=-2x$$
Let $v=\tan (y/2) \implies v'=\sec^@(y/2) (y/2) \implies v'=\frac{1}{2} \sec^2(y/2) y'$,
The we get a linear ODE:
$$v'+v=-x \implies v=-e^{-x} \int e^{x} x+ Ce^{-x}\implies v=(1-x)+C e^{-x}$$
Finally, $$y=2\tan^{-1}[(1-x)+Ce^{-x}].$$

Comment: Oh! I am very sorry it was a typo, I have corrected. The substitution id $v=\tan (y/2)$.

Comment: What do you mean with $\sec^@$? and the $(y/2)(y/2)$ following afterwards?